# HTTP post request is getting intermittently called via C# client in mule 3.6

Tags: mule

I am hosting webservice using mule 3.6.
I observed POST HTTP request is working fine with java client. But C# client this webservice is getting called intermittently i.e first call is ok, second time out , third call is ok , fourth time out and so on.
GET HTTP request is working fine with C# client

Below is the sample of mule-flow.xml

```xml
 <http:listener-config name="Port1_WS_Listener" host="0.0.0.0" port="7001"  doc:name="WS Listener">
    <http:worker-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="20" maxThreadsIdle="10" threadTTL="10000" threadWaitTimeout="5000"/>
 </http:listener-config>

 <http:listener-config name="Port2_WS_Listener" host="0.0.0.0" port="7002"  doc:name="WS Listener">
   <http:worker-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="20" maxThreadsIdle="10" threadTTL="10000" threadWaitTimeout="5000"/>
 </http:listener-config>

   <flow name="WSFlow">
      <composite-source> 
         <http:listener config-ref="Port1_WS_Listener" path="getAttributes1"   
                doc:name="Port1 " allowedMethods="POST"/>
         <http:listener config-ref="Port2_WS_Listener" path="getAttributes2"  
                 doc:name="Port2" allowedMethods="POST"/>
       </composite-source>      
       <component doc:name="java : WSHandler">
           <interceptor-stack ref="default" />
           <spring-object bean="httpWSHandler" />
      </component>
      <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
           <logger level="ERROR" message="#[exception]" doc:name="Logger" />
     </catch-exception-strategy>
   </flow>
```

C# client sample code
poststring value would be like param=[{'empId':'123', 'empName':'xyz'}]

```
WebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
webRequest.Method = "POST";                
webRequest.Timeout = Timeout;
byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postString);                
webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; 

 StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream());
writer.WriteLine(postString);
writer.Close();                

WebResponse wsResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine("Response Successful");
Stream dataStream = wsResponse.GetResponseStream();

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
string response = reader.ReadToEnd();
dataStream.Close();
Console.WriteLine("Response Closed");
```

Curl output

Note: in below out parameter value has been replaced with dummy parameter hence content length value may differ

```
About to connect() to localhost port 7002
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 7002
> POST /getAttributes2 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.15.5 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.15.5 OpenSSL/0.9.8
> Host: localhost:7002
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 417
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> param=[{'empId':'123', 'empName':'xyz'}]HTTP/1.1 200
< MULE_ENCODING: US-ASCII
< Content-Length: 719
< Date: Fri, 31 Jul 2015 09:19:20 GMT
Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection #0
[{"company":"xyz","department":"xyz"}]
```

Comment: You need to provide more info if you want us to help you debug your application. Can you provide the C# client code? Also can you reproduce the issue with `curl`? Can you provide the full output of a `curl -v -X POST...` interaction?

Comment: WebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
webRequest.Method = "POST";                
webRequest.Timeout = Timeout;
byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postString);                
webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; 
    
 StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream());
writer.WriteLine(postString);
writer.Close();

Comment: Please edit your question to add the extra stuff I asked, don't paste it in comments. It's unreadable.

Comment: Hi, @DavidDossot Could you please provide some of your expert guidance on this issue? User has edited the question as per your advise. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see anything that could explain this weird behaviour :'(

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out solution , seems we need to use http-proxy like below

[HTTP Proxy](https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/HTTP+Proxy+Pattern)

```
<pattern:http-proxy name="http-proxy-sample">
    <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://0.0.0.0:10011/getEmployeeAttributesProxy" />
    <http:outbound-endpoint address="http://0.0.0.0:10001/getEmployeeAttributes" />
</pattern:http-proxy>
```

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem with C# HTTP POST requests going through the APIKit to the new HTTP Listener to the same flow in rapid succession.  I worked around it by switching back to the deprecated HTTP Inbound Endpoint, where it is not a problem.

```
<http:inbound-endpoint doc:name="HTTP" exchange-pattern="request-response"    path="api/v1/" host="${http.cs-testing-tools.host}" port="${http.cs-testing-tools.port}" />
```

When monitoring the flows using Mule Management Console, the calls which timeout are never registered by Mule, so it appears that the HTTP listener never gets a payload to process.

Nov 18 2015 UPDATE - After some discussion with Mule support, this is caused by the interaction between C# and the library used by the new HTTP Listener.  The behavior manifests as every other POST timing out.

You can work around this on the C# side as follows:

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
httpWebRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
```

Comment: this is rather a comment

Answer (score 0):

You can add Settings to `app.config` or `web.config` in your C# project

```
<system.net>
  <settings> 
    <servicePointManager expect100Continue="false"/>  
  </settings> 
</system.net>
```